# Google Drive API - is it possible to get file relative to shared path?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a directory (shared_dir) on Google Drive that is shared to everyone,
with a shared link of e.g. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/123456...4rzj?usp=sharing
The directory structure under the parent is fixed.

```
shared_dir
├── sub_dir1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.jpg
│── file3.mp4
```

I need to access files in this directory.
I can use the Google Drive API to make a query, to get all the files that have a parent with shared_dir.fileId (see snippet1).
But this looks to me like a waste (in terms of processing, query time, complication).
Given that the directory structure is fixed, I'm looking for a way to reach the files by their relative location to shared_dir.

Something like:

```
get https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/123456...4rzj/sub_dir1/file1.txt
```

My use case is that my app calls say 100 of files under the shared_dir.
If shared_dir is removed and then added and shared again, it will have a new folderId, and so will all the nested files.

If I can get the files with relative path, then I only have to update the link to the shared_dir (to include the new folderId).
But if not, then I have to update many links for every file (even if this is done programaticaly).

**Is there a way to reach the files by their relative location to shared_dir?**

Thanks

---

*snippet1 - Google Drive API call to get all the files that have a parent with shared_dir.fileId*

```
    service = get_gdrive_service()
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        q = "'123456...4rzj' in parents", pageSize=50, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, size, parents, modifiedTime)").execute()
    # get the results
    items = results.get('files', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#python), you need to specify the parent folder ID every time to search files under a specific folder.

If you only put the name, for example:  `name = 'hello'`, the API would interpret this as searching files with the name `hello` on the root directory, in this case, My Drive.

From a code perspective, you would need to declare a `const` that contains the `folder_id`, if you are sure that the directory structure is fixed.

For your use case, you might need a query like this:

```
q = "'123456...4rzj' in parents and name = 'hello'"
```

Comment: I'm ok with putting the folder_id of the shared_dir). My question is, if there is a way to avoid putting the fileId to get to specific file and instead use the folder_id together with relative path...

Comment: The ````q```` parameter on the ````list()```` method accepts file names (or substrings of file names) such as ````name = 'hello'````, so there is no need to know the fileId in advance.

Comment: But what if you have 2 files with the name 'hello.txt' (sub_dir1/hello.txt, and sub_dir2/hello.txt). Can I do something like q = "'123456...4rzj' in parents and name = 'sub_dir2/hello.txt'" ?  
I'm trying to understand if there is a notion of **file-system structure** that I can use in my queries.

Comment: Google Drive's file system is different and there's no concept of file path, only file name and parent name